# How much helium should I put in a weather balloon?

Tags: meteorology

I have an 8 foot diameter weather balloon and I plan to launch it into near space. I was hoping someone out there in this community would know about weather balloons. My payload will problably weigh around 3 pounds. How much helium should I put in for maximum bursting point? Here’s a link to the balloon: [Weather balloon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004I45LX0). Thanks in advance!

(I also asked this question on the space exploration community, in case anybody there has done this before.)

Comment: "Great for Parties!". I love parties.

Comment: I think about 2-3 $m^3$.

Comment: Be sure to contact the FAA when you use it. But I don't think this is a high quality weather balloon. Different details, besides the "Great for Parties," headline, including the msspelling of "weather," lead me to believe this particular weather balloon might be a ripoff.

Comment: Current helium prices could put the parties into danger ...

Comment: Okay, thanks for the advice. I found a more reliable one for $50.